# Installing MariaMole (Alternative IDE) on Mac

Tags: ide

I've heard about a alternative Arduino IDE called [MariaMole](https://github.com/aporto/mariamole) and really liked the idea, but I just don't know how to install it on Mac OS X. The [GitHub page](https://github.com/aporto/mariamole) claims that it is compatible with Mac but I just can't find a tutorial, or instructions, as to how the Git files can be compiled on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I haven't tried this myself so YMMV; this is just from my general experience and reading; all information comes with citations.*

To start, I would recommend opening [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aporto/mariamole/issues) to ask for detailed instructions. I noticed that the [website](http://dalpix.com/mariamole-download) says:

> Linux and Mac distributions are still experimental, but MariaMole is working fine on both systems.

so they should have a known recipe for how to do it.

---

In the mean time, here's how I would proceed. Given that there's a file called [`CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/aporto/mariamole/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) in the root directory, you need to:

- download and install [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/)

Then, install the [dependencies listed on the wiki](https://github.com/aporto/mariamole/wiki/Compiling-MariaMole):

- Qt 5.2
- QScintilla 2
- QSerial

After that, I presume just cloning the repo and running `cmake` in the root directory should do the trick. If you have any further questions, please open an issue on GitHub with your compilation error message for further assistance.

Comment: can not find any instruction how to build it.
Just call "cmake" in the root dir does not do anything.
I try to build on Linux.

Comment: @wally - you have to run `cmake` in the root (or top level) directory of where ever you unzipped, or downloaded, the MariaMole source packages.

Answer (score 0):

For mac its not yet released ([See website](http://dalpix.com/mariamole-download)).

To try the experimental mac version, you'll have to compile it yourself with the code found on that github repository you linked to

Comment: Actually i'm asking how i compile those source files.